# UV mapping - nothing shows in UV / Image Editor

Tags: uv

When I try to unwrap my mesh, nothing shows up in my UV/Image editor window.

I have tried simple and complex parts, imported and native mesh, all same result.
Nothing shows up when I hit unwrap.

Comment: Try loading an image into the editor.

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem, I simply just have to create a new image (named whatever you like) in the UV/Image editor window. After you've done so, try unwrapping your model again from the 3D view.

Also, selecting all of your model in edit mode (A key) helps to see the map reflected in the UV/Image workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first select all vertices (press <kbd>A</kbd>) while in Edit Mode, in order to see them in the UV/Image Editor. Also, you need to select the vertices before Unrapping.